# predicateWithBlock: passes NSDictionaryMapNode

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Sometimes, when I try to use an `NSPredicate` with an `NSFetchRequest`, the `evaluatedObject` it passes to the block is either `nil` or an instance of `NSDictionaryMapNode`, which nobody ever seems to have heard of.

Obviously this is problematic because the `NSDictionaryMapNode` is not part of a public API and has no useful methods that I need to use for my predicate.

Here's a really simple example:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([evaluatedObject class]);
    return YES;
}];
```

**Here I am expecting `evaluatedObject` to be an instance of a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, but instead it is an instance of `NSDictionaryMapNode`.**

**I've investigated this further, and it seems that this happens every time I perform a fetch after the first, which works fine.** I don't know if it's maybe something to do with deallocation or if I use something twice that I shouldn't.

Comment: Are you using an SQLite store? You can't use predicateWithBlock: with an FRC and SQLite store because it can't be converted into the required format to run against the SQLite store.

Comment: @Wain I'm using Core Data, so I don't think I'm using SQLite, but then I don't know that much about it.

Comment: Core data can either use an in-memory, binary or SQLite store. You specify which when you setup the core data stack (before you create the managed object context).

Comment: @Wain I have this line in my App Delegate: `NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];`. I assume that that means I am using an in-memory store.

Comment: It does. So, sometimes you receive the correct class? And sometimes the private class?

Comment: The first time I do any request, I get the correct class. Any subsequent requests give me the error.

Comment: Do you reuse the fetch or create a new one? What happens in between the 'runs'? Do you make any changes to the model outside of RestKit?

Comment: @Wain When I request again with the same view controller, the fetch request is reused. When I request with a different view controller, a new fetch request is used. I don't make any model changes outside of RestKit.

Comment: Are the objects in your Core Data model marked "transient"?

Comment: @CodaFi Umm… I have no idea… How can I check?

Comment: If you're fetching a transient property (there should be a tick box for it in the Xcode store modeller), then there's the very large possibility that it will be deallocated the second time 'round.  It may be, however, that your store is deallocating the objects in the fetch request before the predicate can enumerate them.

Comment: @CodaFi transient is not checked for any of the attributes.

Comment: @CodaFi given that it's sometimes `nil` I think that it's very likely the objects are being deallocated. Is there a way I can prevent this? I'm using ARC.

Comment: Can you check the error parameter on your fetch request to see what Core Data thinks has gone wrong, first?

Comment: @CodaFi looks like it isn't getting an error. Weird.

Comment: @CodaFi even stranger, if I just `return YES;` from the predicate and then examine the `fetchedObjects` property of the fetched results controller, the classes are correct.

Comment: Yeah, Core Data classes do weird things when you log 'em.

Comment: @CodaFi It's not just that they're being logged that way. I can send them messages after the predicate has been applied, but I can't inside the predicate.

Comment: Makes... Sense.  They should all be faults in the predicate.  You're probably just firing them all one by one by accessing properties like this.

Comment: @CodaFi So I can't access properties in a predicate?

Comment: @RossPenman 1. The fact, that the behavior starts with the second execution of the request let me think, that it is related to object uniquing.http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html
2. You will find class dumps in the net for NSDictionaryMapNode and NSStoreMapNode, its superclass. It looks like a proxy on the first view.
3. Why do you care about the class? Did you try KVC on it?
4. If KVC does not work for you, try to get simply the objectID via KVC and log it. (Only for investigating, what's going on.)

Comment: @Amin I care about the class because I need to access a property as part of my predicate.

Comment: @RossPenman You cannot do that with KVC?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sorry, got confused with KVO. This works perfectly! Submit as an answer so I can give you the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is the result of [uniquing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) done by core data. See my comment.

Try to access the properties via key-value coding.

Comment: What if I want to call a method?

Comment: -valueForKey: is a method. ;-) Just try it. It depends on the proxy implementation. (if it is a proxy as it seems to be.) But you should rarely need it, because the predicate should be evaluatable through the object's outer state.

Comment: `valueForKey:` works because it's declared on NSObject, which NSDictionaryMapNode inherits from (I presume). But I'd like to call a method on the `NSManagedObject` subclass. I can get around it, but it was basically just by copying the method body into the predicate.

Comment: Or it is a subclass of NSProxy. (I really do not know, check it out.) What I wanna say is, that it does not have to be a subclass of $whatever. A proxy responds to selectors, the origin responds to, even it is not a subclass of it. Do not think in classes, this is Objective-C.

Comment: `NSDictionaryMapNode : NSStoreMapNode : NSObject`. It's not a proxy and won't respond to `NSManagedObject` messages I send it.

Comment: You tried it out as I suggested? Than try to get the objectID through KVC and get the original object, if it is really neccessary. But this should not be neccessary to evaluate a predicate. What does the method do? If it changes the object's state you should not execute it to prevent side efects.If it does not, it looks like a getter.

Comment: I'll have to research `objectID`. This method is basically just a fancy getter that computes the return value rather than storing it in an instance variable.

Comment: Did you try to add the calculated property to the entity type as transient property and using KVC? I do not really believe that this works, but you should try it. (BTW: A proxy does not necessarily have to be a NSProxy subclass.)